# Symfony2 Service Response

Tags: php, symfony, service, response

i was trying to setup a general service which handles common function i use very often everywhere in my project. For example if a user wants to purchase something for virtual currency there would be a function which checks, if the user has enough virtual currency in his account.

If the user doesnt have enough virtual currency I want this function to make a JSOn Response, but of cource, only controllers are allowed to response. But this means i have to check in every action I use this function, whether the purchase is valid or not.

Here is the function call in my Controller:

```
$purchaes= $this->get('global_functions')->payVirtualCurrency($user_id,  $currency_amount);
if($change instanceof JsonResponse){
    return $change;
}
```

And the function:

```
public function payVirtualCurrency($user_id, $currency_amount){
    $user = $this->dm->getRepository('LoginBundle:User')->findOneById($user_id);
    if($user->getVirtualCurrency() < $currency_amount){
        return new JsonResponse(array('error' => $this->trans->trans('Insufficient amount of virtual Currency')));
    }
    return true;
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? I really want to avoid doing the same thing in the controller over and over again.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Two options come to my mind, both are quite elegant solutions but both require little work:

**1. Create custom exception listener**

Create  custom exception, let's call it `InsufficientMoneyException`. Then, your sevice can be as it is, but instead of returning response it throws your custom exception (in case user does not have enough money). Then, you [create custom exception listener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/service_container/event_listener.html) which listenes to `InsufficientMoneyException` custom exception and returns your desired `JsonResponse`.

**2. Create custom annotation**

You can create custom annotation and flag a controller action with this annotation. It would look something like this

```
/**
* @MinimumMoneyRequired("50")
*/
public function buyAction()
{
(...)
}
```

This option is really nice and decoupled but it require quite a lot of configuration. This is nice [blog post](http://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/03/symfony2-creating-a-metadata-factory-for-processing-custom-annotations/) with detailed description how to create custom annotations